# How to start TMUX with prespecified number of panes and size

Tags: linux, macos, unix, tmux

Is there a way to start a tmux with fixed number of panes open and predefined size?
What I mean is that, whenever I do this in my terminal:

```
$ tmux
```

It will open a session with 4 panes and each of them with my preferred size that looks
like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how to do it in `~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: Maybe you can save your tmux session with those panes and restore it next time. Check this script : https://github.com/mislav/dotfiles/blob/d2af5900fce38238d1202aa43e7332b20add6205/bin/tmux-session

Answer (score 4):

tmuxinator (https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) allows you pre-define your session (window, pane...etc.) in a config file, and start tmux with that config.

I wrote a tool: retmux (https://github.com/sk1418/retmux), has the similar functionalities. Instead of editing your config file, with retmux, you can just in your tmux doing your pane(with layout)/window/path setting, when you were satisfied with your current session, do a `retmux -b [name]`, retmux will save a backup(config) for your sessions, next time when you want to restore that session(s), just `retmux -r [name]` check the project page for detailed info.